# Change regex to be insensitive to order of words in a list of strings in R

Tags: r, regex, list, function

I wonder why:

`setNames(First_list, sub("^.([^_]+)\\D+(\\d+).*", "Gain_\\2(\\1)", names(First_list)))` can produce my `Desired_output` but:

`setNames(Second_list, sub("^.([^_]+)\\D+(\\d+).*", "Gain_\\2(\\1)", names(Second_list)))` can not produce my `Desired_output`?

`First_list` and `Second_list` are the same except the order of words in them is reversed. Can the regex be modified to produce the same `Desired_ouput` for `First_list` and `Second_list`?

```
First_list <-
  list(`(beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline)`= 1,
       `(intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)`= 1,
       `(advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline)`= 1,
       `(beginner_post2 - beginner_baseline)`= 1,
       `(intermediate_post2 - intermediate_baseline)`= 1,
       `(advanced_post2 - advanced_baseline)`= c(7,-1),
       `(framework notes_posttest1 - framework notes_baseline)`=1,
       `(note-taking instruction_posttest1 - note-taking instruction_baseline)`=1
  )  
  
  
Second_list <- 
list(`(post1_beginner - baseline_beginner)` = 1,
     `(post1_intermediate - baseline_intermediate)` = 1,
     `(post1_advanced - baseline_advanced)` = 1, 
     `(post2_beginner - baseline_beginner)` = 1,
     `(post2_intermediate - baseline_intermediate)` = 1,
     `(post2_advanced - baseline_advanced)` = 1,
     `(posttest1_framework notes - baseline_framework notes)`=1,
     `(posttest1_note-taking instruction - baseline_note-taking instruction)`=1
   )

Desired_output = 
  list("Gain_1(beginner)"= 1,
       "Gain_1(intermediate)"= 1,
       "Gain_1(advanced)"= 1,
       "Gain_2(beginner)"= 1,
       "Gain_2(intermediate)"= 1,
       "Gain_2(advanced)"= 1,
       "Gain_1(framework notes)" = 1,
       "Gain_1(note-taking instruction)"=1
  )
```

Comment: Simon please dont delete and repost [identical questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78062916/modifying-list-element-names-in-r-making-regex-insensitive-to-terms-order?noredirect=1#comment137619732_78062916)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the `one1_two` to `two_one1`, keying on the presence of the number, and then do your first regex.

```r
names(First_list) |>
  sub(" - .*", "", x = _) |>
  sub("([- A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)_([- A-Za-z]+)", "\\2_\\1", x = _) |>
  sub("^.([^_]+)\\D+(\\d+).*", "Gain_\\2(\\1)", x = _)
# [1] "Gain_1(beginner)"                "Gain_1(intermediate)"            "Gain_1(advanced)"                "Gain_2(beginner)"               
# [5] "Gain_2(intermediate)"            "Gain_2(advanced)"                "Gain_1(framework notes)"         "Gain_1(note-taking instruction)"
names(Second_list) |>
  sub(" - .*", "", x = _) |>
  sub("([- A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)_([- A-Za-z]+)", "\\2_\\1", x = _) |>
  sub("^.([^_]+)\\D+(\\d+).*", "Gain_\\2(\\1)", x = _)
# [1] "Gain_1(beginner)"                "Gain_1(intermediate)"            "Gain_1(advanced)"                "Gain_2(beginner)"               
# [5] "Gain_2(intermediate)"            "Gain_2(advanced)"                "Gain_1(framework notes)"         "Gain_1(note-taking instruction)"
```

The swap does nothing with `First_list` but "fixes" `Second_list` so that it looks like the first. From there, the same pattern works.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I just noticed that your output for `First_list` and `Second_list` aren't the same. For example, the output for the former has `"Gain_1(framework notes)"` but this is `"Gain_1(framework)"` and `"Gain_1(note)"` for the latter.